# If mounting a TV bracket on a brick wall, is it safe to use the existing holes from an old bracket?

Tags: walls

I live in the uk and the wall construction in the house is 1930s red brick. The previous owners of the house had their TV mounted on the living room wall (actually the load-bearing party wall with the neighbours, so it should be of good, solid construction). If the bracket we have fits the existing holes, is it safe to reuse them? If so, is there anything I should do in order to prepare the holes for the new rawl plugs?

Comment: Just a thought, but I'll bet that putting holes in shared walls may compromise the fire separation the wall should provide.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, as long as the material around the holes is sound and the holes are the correct size for the fasteners or anchors.

Comment: And the anchors and fasteners are designed for use in that material and are rated for the combined weight of TV and bracket.

Comment: Sure, but that wasn't really the question.